# What's the best way to keep your shirt tucked in?

Tags: clothing

I find myself needing to put my shirt back inside my trousers throughout the day because it keeps coming untucked. This can be very awkward to do.  What is the best way to keep a shirt tucked in?

I've tried safety pins but I ended up with torn shirts. Anything better out there?

Comment: You need to buy your shirts a bit longer

Answer (score 12):

As [mentioned before](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/1587/32) there are [commercial products](http://www.shirtstay.com/) available to solve this problem:

[image]

But that would be expensive and wouldn't be a proper life hack.

To save a little money you could just re-purpose an old pair of suspenders, you should be able to find them in thrift stores, provided you don't have a significant hipster population in your area...

[image]

With this style of suspenders you can carefully remove the stitching, to separate the two elastic strips. Then you will have two working sock/shirt garters for around $2.

Answer (score 7):

You *could* buy [shirt stays](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001TLBZYE)...

But that's not very hacky. So I recommend using [safety pins](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00566E8DI) to attach your shirt to your underwear.

My personal solution is to never tuck my shirt in. You might think this would make you look sloppy, however you can avoid this fate by judicious cultivation of unkempt facial hair to distract folks' attention.

Comment: Safety pins can lead to torn underwear and shirts if you stretch or otherwise expand your expected range of motion.

Answer (score 4):

Longer torso length shirts would be my first choice (and recommended by other people for this question).

Double sided tape would be my second choice. There are lots of products out there specifically made for this (i.e., Hollywood Fashion Tape, double sided stylist tape, etc.). You could even use duct tape in an emergency (not recommended as the glue doesn't come off clothing easily).

If you need to make temporary (emergency) double sided tape, you have some options:

1. Make small loops of regular tape with the glue facing out. This method may require lots of loops to prevent the clothing from slipping.

[image]

2. Make a long loop of regular tape with the glue facing out. At some interval, place a holding loop around the longer loop to prevent it from sliding apart. You could think of this assembly like cable ties around cables.

[image: The right most piece of string is what I am trying to describe, just with tape.]

3. Using two pieces of tape that are approximately the same length, put the glue sides together where about half of the glue is not covered by the other piece of tape.

Comment: What;s the point of the strings? Just to help form tape pieces? Or do you use the string on the pant?

Answer (score 4):

I presume you are wearing an undershirt under your dress shirt and, if so, then...

1. Tuck your undershirt inside your underwear, then
2. Pull on your trousers or slacks or jeans, then
3. Tuck your dress shirt into your pants, button up, zip up and fasten your          belt.

I was told this method by a tailor more than 30 years ago and it has kept me looking neat, and it should work for you as well.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Just tuck your shirt into your underwear really well and then pull your trousers on over the top. Stretch your arms up to loosen it a little so it doesn't look too tight and to prevent the possibility of a wedgie. This works for me.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to downvote this, but it's a great way to make your underwear stick out.

Comment: +1 Objectively, this is an effective way to keep the shirt tucked in! Ha! I have a physic teacher who did this. Very funny to see the underwear riding up his back!

Comment: You can also tuck the front of your shirt into your underwear, and the back of your shirt over your underwear, then pull your trousers up.  That way if your underwear shows in the front, you can at least see it.

Answer (score 1):

## How to keep your shirt tucked in

Keeping your shirt tucked in can be a bit of a hassle at times. I know that it happens to me all the time, I make the slightest movement and my shirt just pops out of place. I started tucking my shirt into my underwear at first and I liked it because it was really quick and convenient but then I noticed that my underwear would touch my "areas" and I started searching for other solutions. I found a few on the market like shirt stays, and shirt garters. You can find them on amazon or google. I tried them and they did the job ok but the only think I didn't like about them was how cumbersome they can be. You have to take too much time in the mornings to put them on and sometimes the hooks would come undone and the straps would hang down in the pants and/or hit the ground ( quite annoying ) .

That's when I began searching for a boxer brief that could do the job I was searching for. I mean, I was already tucking my shirt into my own underwear so I figured, maybe there was a boxer brief that might do the trick and that's when I bumped into the product [Tucked Trunks](http://www.tuckedtrunks.com) . I found them on facebook actually and I was a little skeptical at first but I decided to order a pair and give them a shot. I got them and I have to say, I love them. The most important thing that I loved about them is that they are SUPER easy to use, no strings, no gadgets, no magnets it's pretty much a boxer brief but it has a dual waistband with rubber inside to really grip the shirt , and a slit in the front so you put the last button of your shirt into it to keep it even more tucked in place. I have to admit after I started wearing these trunks, I literally cannot leave home without them. They are just so easy and feel great.

That's the solution that I found that works for me. Hopefully that will help everyone also. Here's the link to [keep your shirt tucked in](http://www.tuckedtrunks.com) .

Comment: Please read [How not to be a spammer](/help/promotion) - you need to declare your affiliation with this site.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good answers on this post but I always suggest others to use [Duct Tape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duct_tape) just like some of my hill billy red neck cousins do. You have someone help wrap the bottom of you shirt with a couple round around the bottom of the shirt, and then pull your pants up right over the duct taped shirt and the extra weight and texture helps keep it stable.

If you need to get extreme, you can do so with this stuff too. See the below screen shots of the normal and the extreme methods but the application is higly customizable with this stuff for your needs.

### Maggies Typical Method

[image]

### Jim Bob's Extreme Method

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possibilities to keep the **lower end of your shirt** below the upper limit **belt-line of your trousers**.

Many of the solutions presented have been focussed on the **fastening** with pins, clips, or adhesive tapes or by purchasing increased lengths of the lower end of the shirt. Some techniques appear to be severe.

Alternately, you may be wearing your trouser belt-line too low for your normal daily routine and your body shape and proportions.

The ***hack*** for your situation until you can affect a permanent solution (proper-fitting clothing) is to **wear your pants higher around your waistline**. **Wear your pants at a height sufficient to keep your shirt tails in place** below your waistline. You might even want to wear suspenders to deal with this situation. Suspenders allow you to wear slightly looser pants that will more easily ride up and down as you lift and lower your arms. They are more comfortable than wearing a belt for many.

In the future, if you feel your trouser belt finding its normal position on your body lower than will accommodate your present shirt-tail length, seek longer shirts that will suit your body proportions and belt-line trouser length.

Answer (score 0):

Get yourself some alligator clips, like these:
[image]

Then, get some rubber bands, and make a chain like this:
[image]

Connect the rubber bands to the screws on the alligator clips, and then clip them to your shirt at one end and your socks at the other end.  Simple!

Maybe not the most practical solution, not to mention maybe a little painful, but hacky for sure.

Comment: I'd use string for most of the length, then just a thick rubber band at one end (or both ends).

Answer (score 0):

Since @RedSonja didn't bother to make this an answer, someone should:

> I find myself realizing my clothes don't fit. What do?

## Buy clothes that fit.

It really isn't any more complicated than that. Anything else is a short-term, less comfortable stopgap. Pay attention to what—besides insufficient length—causes your shirts to come out; it may be the back is too tight on your shoulders and sides; more likely, you don't have enough loose fabric to allow for the range of your arm motions through the course of your workday.